# Gmail keyboard shortcut to indicate meeting attendance

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, keyboard-shortcuts

When I get a meeting (appointment) invitation in my GMail inbox from another Google Apps user, there are links embedded in the message that I can use to indicate my meeting attendance: "Going? Yes - Maybe - No"

Are there keyboard shortcuts that I can use to activate each of these links ("Yes", "Maybe", "No")?

Comment: Did you try pressing the **?** while on Gmail? It shows all the Gmails shortcuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite sure there aren't any specific ones.
The ones you could use are tab and enter.

The only e-mails in which Gmail offers specific hotkeys are the Google+ "e-mails" that are actually Google+ posts in Gmail.

Comment: Thanks.  I did try using Tab, but it took a *lot* of presses of the Tab key to get the focus all the way over to the Yes / Maybe / No links!

Answer (score 7):

There's no way to to this out of the box. I added custom search engine with keyword "yes" and search string

```
javascript:[...document.querySelectorAll('div[role="button"]')].filter(i => i.textContent === 'Yes')[0].click()
```

and named it 'Say "yes" to Google Calendar invitation'.

And the other one with keyword "no" and search string

```
javascript:[...document.querySelectorAll('div[role="button"]')].filter(i => i.textContent === 'No')[0].click()
```

and named it 'Say "no" to Google Calendar invitation'.

You can also create "Maybe" if you want to.

To run it you should focus URL panel (Ctrl + L or Cmd + L) and they type "yes" or "no" depending on your decision.

**How does it work?**

Instead of loading search engine URL, this custom engine will execute a small piece of JavaScript. This piece of JavaScript first searches for a button with the appropriate text on the page and then clicks it.

Comment: That is awesome!  Thanks for sharing this -- I'm new to web development and keep forgetting that JavaScript can do things like this.

Answer (score 1):

An [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) shortcut, sending the necessary keystrokes, may be an alternate solution. FWIW, an AutoHotkey shortcut is called a [Hotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).

AutoHotkey is a Windows OS solution. For alternative solutions you may find help [here](https://alternativeto.net/software/autohotkey/).